# Restrict scripts to a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to integrate old affiliates headers in my site. This is turning into a real headache as their scripts and CSS files often collide with mine. If I use jquery in my page and the header I integrate has a reference to an older version jquery I will get a lot of JavaScript errors on my page. I cannot add the header to an iframe because they often have nav-bars with dropdowns and I will have to assign the header the whole view if he has a big dropdown. Does anyone have a solution to my problem that doesn't involve iframes? Thanks!

Comment: You can try using jquery's no-conflict mode to have multiple versions of jquery on the same page:  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if your problem with adding a different version of jquery to your specific page,
if that's can simply add your different version in your specific page that you really need

for example
create your full file with your Jquery with name example.php
then in the main page you want to include your file in
create an empty div with class example
use jquery .load function to load your example file in your example page

```
example.php
echo (<h3>Hello World</h3>);
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('h3').click(function(){
     alert('Ok');
});
</script>
```

then in main.php

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<script>
 $(function(){
     $('.foo').load(path/to/example.php);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `jQuery.noConflict()` Documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

W3 Schools has an explanation for using

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

It resets the `$` variable with whatever you set it to in order to avoid conscious with other libraries or versions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Could you may provide more information then just one line of code?